# Convert String to DateTime in flutter

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart

I have this code

```
if (obj.due_date != null) {
      print('The date is  '+obj.due_date);
      print('now change to ' +
       DateUtil().formattedDate(DateTime.parse(obj.due_date)));
 }
```

**DateUtil**

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class DateUtil {
  static const DATE_FORMAT = 'dd/MM/yyyy';
  String formattedDate(DateTime dateTime) {
    print('dateTime ($dateTime)');
    return DateFormat(DATE_FORMAT).format(dateTime);
  }
}
```

My output become this

> I/flutter ( 5209): The date is  2019-11-20T00:00:00.000+08:00
>
> I/flutter ( 5209): dateTime (2019-11-19 16:00:00.000Z)
>
> I/flutter ( 5209): now change to 19/11/2019

Why it will change from 20 to 19?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because of the value that you hold in

`obj.due_date`

As per the log, the current value is

> 2019-11-20T00:00:00.000+08:00

When I used the below code

```
var tempDate = '2019-11-20T00:00:00.000+00:00';
print('The date is  '+tempDate);
print('now change to ' +DateUtil().formattedDate(DateTime.parse(tempDate)));
```

the logs are as follows:

```
I/flutter (18268): The date is  2019-11-20T00:00:00.000+00:00
I/flutter (18268): dateTime (2019-11-20 00:00:00.000Z)
I/flutter (18268): now change to 20/11/2019
```

The only change between these codes is the value that we pass.

> 2019-11-20T00:00:00.000+00:00

It is purely a timezone issue.

Try below code

```
var tempDate = DateTime.now().toLocal().toString();
```

Log show

```
I/flutter (18268): 2019-11-15 16:06:54.786814
I/flutter (18268): The date is  2019-11-15 16:06:54.787186
I/flutter (18268): dateTime (2019-11-15 16:06:54.787186)
I/flutter (18268): now change to 15/11/2019
```

Likewise, when you use the following code

```
var tempDate = DateTime.now().toUtc().toString();
```

the logs are as follows:

```
I/flutter (18268): 2019-11-15 16:07:35.078897 
I/flutter (18268): The date is  2019-11-15 05:07:35.079251Z 
I/flutter (18268): dateTime (2019-11-15 05:07:35.079251Z) 
I/flutter (18268): now change to 15/11/2019
```

Hence the final answer is, change below line

```
DateUtil().formattedDate(DateTime.parse(tempDate)));
```

to

```
DateUtil().formattedDate(DateTime.parse(tempDate).toLocal())
```