# How to Convert String to DateTime in flutter?

Tags: flutter, datetime

[image]

How to convert this string to DateTime in flutter ?

Comment: [Datetime.parse](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.5/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html) method. Check that your string is an acceptable format

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert String time and date to DateTime - Dart/Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70439617/convert-string-time-and-date-to-datetime-dart-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do so is that

```
DateTime.parse(StringDate.toString());
```

Comment: "FormatException: Invalid date format " I got This error

Comment: Can you share what you're passing?